# can't iterate through a nodelist in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and having a problem with a nodelist type.

```
var compoentChange = document.getElementById("component_change");
var items = compoentChange.getElementsByTagName("option");
```

When I `console.log(items)`, it shows `[item: function]`. When I expand it, it has all the option elements and length property.

The problem is that I can't access those elements. When I `console.log(items.length)`, I get `undefined`.

How do I iterate through `items` variable?

`for(i in items){}` and `for` loop do not work.

Comment: Could you show the exact output of `console.log(items)`? Some of what you describe is really weird.

Comment: Why do you expect the members of the [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) to be enumerable? The W3C DOM Core specification doesn't say they should be, it only notes one attribute (`length`) and one method (`item`).

Comment: @bfavaretto // the exact output is [item: function] and when I expand it, it has 0: Option ~ x: Option, length: 65, __proto: NodeList

Comment: @RobG // because..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList says so..?

Comment: @Moon—[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Project:About) isn't a specification, it's a wiki created by interested persons that **anyone** can edit. It's largely based on observed behaviour in Mozilla browsers (with a bit, but not much, cross browser help). The W3C creates web standards, not Mozilla Corporation (though Mozilla is represented on the W3C, as is Microsoft, Apple, Sun, etc.).

Comment: @RobG // You're right.

Comment: @Moon—it's a little confusing because `in` does work with element (and probably Node in general) attributes as is sort of specified by HTML5. But I think it's a little inconsistent in older versions of IE.

Comment: Is there any solution. I met the same problem. I can't reach the element. But console logs `[item: function]`

Answer (score 1):

You can still do `items.length`, so just make a for loop like this. I suggest pushing it into an array.

```
var myArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
     myArray.push(items[i]);
}
```

Alright if this isn't an option maybe try something like this:

```
var myArray = [];
for(var i=0, e=1; i<e; i++ ){
   if(items[i] != undefined){
      e++;
      myArray.push(items[i]);
   }else{
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, but there's no need to create an array from a NodeList just for access. It can be handy for other reasons though.

Comment: when I console.log(items) and expand it on my inspector, yes I see the lengh property has a value. The problem is that it's undefined when I console.log(items.length) in my code.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

@RobG, I do this because I often want to do `items.indexOf()`, and that's not available for NodeLists, so I push to an array.

Comment: @Kolby // jsfiddle will work. It works on my box as well. It just doesn't work if I put the code into a chrome plugin.

Comment: @Moon, edited a new option. I didn't test it, but the logic seems right.

Answer (score 1):

NodeLists are array-like objects. You can iterate with regular `for` loop (not `for..in`):

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { ... }
```

Or you can convert this array-like object to a real array and use native array methods on it:

```
[].forEach.call(items, function(item) { ... });
```

Comment: Please don't treat host objects like native objects. The above works in "modern" browsers, but will fail in a good number of older browsers (e.g. IE 8 doesn't have `forEach` and even if it did, its `Function.prototype.call` only works with native objects, not host objects).

Comment: @RobG // this is chrome ONLY question. Look at the tags.

Comment: I've tried both of them. It works if I try them in inspector or just a plain webpage, but not in chrome extension.

Comment: @Moon—Fair enough, but worth the warning. It may be a Chrome plug–in now, but may well end up in web document.

Comment: @RobG: Even though OP asked for Chrome specifically I think that's out of the scope of this question. I don't see the necessity of always having to list browser support in every answer. I mean, IE9 is 3 years old, I'm already assuming a modern browser and host objects can simply be iterated this way without side-effects AFAIK.

Comment: @Moon: Not sure what the problem is. I don't have much experience with Chrome-extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're logging the two during the pageload, the reason that you can console.log() the `NodeList`, but not the `length` attribute is because the `NodeList` is a "live" collection. Both are undefined until the DOM finishes loading, but because the `NodeList` is live, it will update in the Chrome console. The `length`attribute was undefined when it was logged, and because it's not live, it'll stay `undefined` in the console.

You can set a variable to reference the nodeList at any time, but wait until the DOM is ready before trying to use the data (using the `document.ready` function or perhaps `document.addEventListener()`).

Answer (score 0):

I met similar problem with you. It turns out that it is because I should access data after DOM finishes loading.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    console.log(divs);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

for...of can be used for this situation. However due to [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401699), this opportunity cannot be used on chromium.

Comment: please improve this answer